# How to make field required only if the form is new?

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following buildForm method:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder                        
        ->add('firstname','text',array('label'=>'First Name'))
        ->add('lastname','text',array('label'=>'Last Name'))
        ->add('dob','date',array('widget'=>'single_text','label'=>'DOB'))
        ->add('username','text',array('label'=>'Username'))
        ->add('password','password',array('label'=>'Password'))
        ->add('filesPassword','password',array('label'=>'My Files Password','required'=>false))
        ->add('email','email',array('label'=>'Email'))
        ->add('language','entity',array('class'=>'GWD\AdminBundle\Entity\Languages','label'=>'Language'))
        ->add('theme','entity',array('class'=>'GWD\AdminBundle\Entity\Themes','label'=>'Theme'))
        ->add('roles','entity',array('class'=>'GWD\AdminBundle\Entity\Role','label'=>'Role'))
    ;
}
```

How can I dynamically set the password field to be required only upon creating a new record and set it non required when updating a record?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try code below:

```
$builder
  ->add('password','password',
        array(
               'label' => 'Password', 
               'required' => is_null($builder->getData()->getId())
             )
       )
```

Comment: This was the easiest and shortest way to accomplish what I wanted! Thanks so much!

Comment: This solution didn't work for me as is as `$builder->getData()` never returned the corresponding entity data. I had to use the [event listener described in the Symfony2 Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) mixed with this solution code.

Comment: It can happen if you didn't add object to the form.

Comment: @kapa89 Many thanks, gave me a great solution to a stupid problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me with only one caveat, the password field gets added at the end of the form and not in the order I wanted it even though I thought that by adding the event where I wanted the field to appear in, it would do the trick but it didn't.

```
<?php

namespace GWD\AdminBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

class AdministratorsType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder                        
            ->add('firstname','text',array('label'=>'First Name'))
            ->add('lastname','text',array('label'=>'Last Name'))
            ->add('dob','date',array('widget'=>'single_text','label'=>'DOB'))
            ->add('username','text',array('label'=>'Username'));

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event) use ($builder) {
                $administrator = $event->getData();
                if (!$administrator || null === $administrator->getId()) {
                    $event->getForm()->add('password','password',array('label'=>'Password','required'=>true));
                } else {
                    $event->getForm()->add('password','password',array('label'=>'Password','required'=>false));

                }
            }
        );

        $builder
            ->add('filesPassword','password',array('label'=>'My Files Password','required'=>false))
            ->add('email','email',array('label'=>'Email'))
            ->add('language','entity',array('class'=>'GWD\AdminBundle\Entity\Languages','label'=>'Language'))
            ->add('theme','entity',array('class'=>'GWD\AdminBundle\Entity\Themes','label'=>'Theme'))
            ->add('roles','entity',array('class'=>'GWD\AdminBundle\Entity\Role','label'=>'Role'))
        ;

    }


    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'GWD\AdminBundle\Entity\Administrators'
        ));
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'gwd_adminbundle_administrators';
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use, for example, this bundle to rearrange the order https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryOrderedFormBundle

Comment: Great! It looks exactly like what I need, I wonder why this is not a built in feature...

Comment: Except that it looks damaged - I do not see all the files in repository. Do you want to reuse the form in many places or it is only a one-time form? And, BTW, Sonata Admin is a nice bundle for admin interface.

Comment: This is a one place only form. I am rebuilding a legacy application and Sonata Admin looks like it would be too much for me, learning symfony alone has been a challenge, let alone having to learn how Sonata Admin bundle works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You do not need to create a separate class for the form in this case - everything can be done through the controller. The way that you choose is good for the reusable forms. And in controller use can easily defined if this is a new entity or update of existing one.

Comment: You can also add all the fields in the listener. Although that will be slower, if you have multiple instances of the form.

Answer (score -2):

You could add another var to your array where you define labels:

```
->add('firstname','text',array('label'=>'First Name', 'required' => false))
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I know I can do what you suggest but I want to make it required only if its new data being inserted and make it non-required if the data is being updated.